# Virtual Box: Kernel panic - not syncing vfs unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0 0) error

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, kernel-panic

I have downloaded a virtual box application which I'm supposed to directly boot into a Ubuntu Virtual Machine. While doing so, I get the following error:

[image]

From the solutions I've read online, I'm supposed to boot into an older version of the kernel to fix this issue. However, this version of the kernel came packed along with the virtual box application I downloaded and I didn't have to download the Ubuntu image myself. How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is generally what happens when a Linux kernel fails to find a root filesystem. The message "Unable to mount root fs on `unknown-block(0,0)`" means essentially "I don't even know what kind of disk the root filesystem is supposed to be on." If the end of message said something other than `unknown-block(0,0)`, then it would mean "I found the device that is supposed to contain the root filesystem, but I do not understand the contents, maybe there's something wrong with it?"

The kernel version `3.13.0-32-generic` indicates this virtual appliance is based on a *rather old* version of Ubuntu: according to [this answer on AskUbuntu.SE](https://askubuntu.com/a/517140/769591), this kernel version belonged to Ubuntu 14.04.

Typically, such virtual appliances come with recommended settings for the virtualization software. If you just added the virtual disk image into a VirtualBox VM configured for a *modern* version of Ubuntu, no wonder it did not work!

The virtual hard disk controller the VirtualBox provides to the VM is probably currently of a type that is too new, so the virtual Ubuntu 14.04 won't recognize it. You might have to switch to a different virtual hard disk controller type in VirtualBox settings for this VM.

[There are several virtual hard disk controller options in VirtualBox.](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#harddiskcontrollers) You might have to think about which of those controller types existed back in year 2014 when that version of Ubuntu was released: trying NVMe or modern VirtIO options with such an old virtual appliance is probably going to be futile. Try the SAS or SATA options first, then SCSI, and finally IDE if nothing else works.